# Which Data Mining task to retrieve a unique instance

Tags: data-mining, information-retrieval

I'm working with data mining, and I'm familiar with classification, clustering and regression tasks. In classification, one can have a lot of instances (e.g. animals), their features (e.g. number of legs) and a class (e.g. mammal, reptile).

But what I need to accomplish is, given some attributes, including the class attribute, to determine which unique instance I'm referring to (e.g. giraffe). I can supply all known attributes that I have, and if the model can’t figure out the answer, it can ask for another attribute – just analogous to a 20 questions style of game.

So, my question is: does this specific task have a name? It seems to be similar to classification, where the class is unique to each instance, but this wouldn’t fit on the current training models, except perhaps for a decision tree model.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs, denoted *features* in machine learning, are tuples of species (what I think you mean by "instance"), and physical attributes. Your outputs are broader taxonomic ranks. Thus, assigning one to each input is a classification problem. Since your features are incomplete, you want to perform ... *classification with incomplete data*, or *impute missing features*. Searching for these terms will give you enough leads.

(And the other task is properly called *clustering*.)

Comment: I've updated my question with these few term changes. But I don't think this is exactly a classification problem, because you couldn't train a model to predict which class a new instance (tuple) belongs, if the class attribute is unique (like an ID).

Comment: Is the class attribute not a taxonomic group related to the species? I don't understand what you mean when you say it is unique. The setup of asking questions to guide the learner recalls [active learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are looking for simply a **decision tree**.

Except, that you don't train it on your categorial attribute (your "class"), but on the individual instance label.

You need to carefully choose the splitting measure though, as many measures go for class sizes - and all your classes have size 1 now. Finding a good split for the decision tree may involve planning some splits ahead to get an optimal balanced tree. A random forest like approach may be of use to improve the chance of finding a good tree.